# becomeFirstResponder on custom UIAlertView button click

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uialertview

I am using a custom UIAlertView. When the error pops up, I resignedFirstResponder as I wanted. The problem comes about when the user clicks the done button designated by kButtonTitle seen below. I am trying to get the keyboard to pop back up once the user clicks the button recognizing the error. I attempted:

```
if (alert)
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
else
    [_nameTextField becomeFirstResponder];
  }
```

The above didn't seem to change anything. My entire code for the textFieldShouldReturn method is pasted below:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

NSString *name = _nameTextField.text;


if ((name.length > 6) && [name containsString:@" "])
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

} else {



    SCLAlertView *alert = [[SCLAlertView alloc] init];

    alert.backgroundType = Blur;

    NSString *kNoticeTitle = @"Error";

    [alert showNotice:self title:kNoticeTitle subTitle:@"Please input both your first and last name" closeButtonTitle:kButtonTitle duration:0.0f];

    if (alert)
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
    else
        [_nameTextField becomeFirstResponder];

    }

    return YES;
    }
```

Any help or comments are greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use a button with a custom action instead of the default close button.

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
SCLAlertView *alert = [[SCLAlertView alloc] init];

[alert addButton:kButtonTitle actionBlock:^{
   [_nameTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}];

[alert showNotice:self title:kNoticeTitle
         subTitle:@"Please input both your first and last name"
 closeButtonTitle:nil duration:0.0f];
```